# How to get the device primary Gmail id to edit text field

Tags: android, android-edittext, google-account, accountpicker

I want to automatically add device primary gmail id in the edit text field whenever user open the login page.

this is my emailview

```
mEmailView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.account_email);
```

I have mentioned the permission in the Main fest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: @Floem I just want the email address like copy and paste, copy the device primary email and paste it to my emailview edittext field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for my question simple and easy way to put device email into edittext

```
    mEmailView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
    android.accounts.Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext()).getAccounts();
    for (android.accounts.Account account : accounts) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
    possibleEmail = account.name;
    }
    }


    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.account_email);
    t1.setText(possibleEmail);
```